# NHibernate query with distance calculation stored proc

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I have a stored procedure in my database that calculates the distance between two lat/long pairs. This stored procedure is called "DistanceBetween". I have a SQL statement allows a user to search for all items in the Items table ordered by the distance to a supplied lat/long coordinate. The SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT Items.*, dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat1, @lat2, Latitude, Longitude) AS Distance
FROM Items
ORDER BY Distance
```

How do I go about using this query in NHibernate? The Item class in my domain doesn't have a "Distance" property since there isn't a "Distance" column in my Items table. The "Distance" property really only comes into play when the user is performing this search.

Comment: Why don't you create the DistanceBetween method in Linq/Hql/Criteria?

Comment: Paco - Could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Just look at the sql code in the procedure? 
I used this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: Now that the bounty passed, you are not allowed to accept any answer anymore, correct? I know I only saw this q. too late, sorry about that, hope my answer below helps a bit anyway. I'll remove this comment in a few days so as not to clutter the thread.

Comment: @Abel - Correct. Great answer though, thanks for responding. I would mark you as the answer if I could. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically three approaches that can be used, some of which have already been discussed:

1. Use an HQL query or `CreateCriteria`/`ICriteria` query; *downsides:* it is not part of the entities/DAL; *upsides:* it is flexible;
2. Use a property mapping with a `formula`; *downsides:* it is not always feasible or possible, performance can degrade if not careful; *upsides:* it the calculation an integral part of your entities;
3. Create a separate XML HBM mapping file and map to a separate (to be created) entity; *downsides:* it is not part of the base entities; *upsides:* you only call the SP when needed, full control of mapping / extra properties / extensions, can use partial or abstract classes to combine with existing entities.

I'll briefly show an example of option 2 and 3 here, I believe option 1 has been sufficiently covered by others earlier in this thread.

Option two, as in this example, is particularly useful when the query can be created as a subquery of a select statement and when all needed parameters are available in the mapped table. It also helps if the table is not mutable and/or is cached as read-only, depending on how heavy your stored procedure is.

```
<class name="..." table="..." lazy="true" mutable="false>
  <cache usage="read-only" />

    <id name="Id" column="id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Latitude" column="Latitude" type="double" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Longitude" column="Longitude" type="double" not-null="true" />

    <property name="PrijsInstelling"
        formula="(dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat1, @lat2, Latitude, Longitude))"
        type="double" />

    ... etc
</class>
```

If the above is not possible due to restrictions in the mappings, problems with caching or if your current cache settings retrieve one by one instead of by bigger amounts and you cannot change that, you should consider an alternate approach, for instance a separate mapping of the whole query with parameters. This is quite close to the CreateSqlQuery approach above, but forces the result set to be of a certain type (and you can set each property declaratively):

```
<sql-query flush-mode="never" name="select_Distances">
    <return
        class="ResultSetEntityClassHere,Your.Namespace"
        alias="items"
        lock-mode="read" >

        <return-property name="Id" column="items_Id" />
        <return-property name="Latitude" column="items_Latitude" />
        <return-property name="Longitude" column="items_Longitude" />
        <return-property name="Distance" column="items_Distance" />
    </return>

    SELECT 
        Items.*, 
        dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat1, @lat2, Latitude, Longitude) AS Distance
    FROM Items
    WHERE UserId = :userId

</sql-query>
```

You can call this query as follows:

```
List<ResultSetEntityClassHere> distanceList = 
    yourNHibernateSession.GetNamedQuery("select_Distances") 
        .SetInt32("userId", currentUserId)  /* any params go this way */
        .SetCacheable(true)                 /* it's usually good to cache */
        .List<ResultSetEntityClassHere>();  /* must match the class of sql-query HBM */
```

Depending on your needs, you can choose an approach. I personally use the following rule of thumb to decide what approach to use:

- Is the calculation light or can it be cached? *Use `formula` approach;*
- Are parameters needed to be sent to the SP/SQL? *Use `sql-query` + mapping approach;*
- Is the structure of the query (very) variable? *Use `ICriteria` or HQL approach through code.*

About the ordering of the data: when you choose the "formula" or the "sql-query mapping" approach you'll have to do the ordering when you retrieve the data. This is not different then with retrieving data through your current mappings.

**Update:** terrible edit-mistake corrected in the sql-query XML.

Comment: Thanks Abel.  I think I'll go with option #3, but I had one question.  Instead of having the ResultSetEntityClassHere have Id, Latitude, and Longitude properties, would it be possible to have it simply have an Item property and a Distance property?  If so, is there a way to adjust that sql-query configuration to correctly map the Item property?  If not, I'll just add whatever columns I need, but it would be easier to have the entire Item object rather than pick and choose which columns I want this query to return.

Comment: You don't need to map all returned columns. You can return other columns. And you can name your class properties any which way you like. As long as you use `return-property` to match correctly and make sure that the stored procedure understands your input and creates the correct output (i.e., at least the columns you need).

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
session.CreateSqlQuery(@"SELECT {item.*}, dbo.DistanceBetween(:lat1, :lat2, {item}.Latitude, {item}.Longitude) AS Distance
    FROM Items {item}
    ORDER BY Distance")
        .AddEntity("item", typeof(Item))
        .SetDecimal("lat1", lat1)
        .SetDecimal("lat2", lat2)
        .List<Item>()
```

NHibernate is finicky about table & column aliases in the query, so you need to let it expand them using the {} syntax. Also, use the HQL named parameter syntax (:lat1 instead of @lat1), and change SetDecimal() to the correct data type.

Comment: Yes, that works, but the result is a list of Item objects which don't have a Distance property.  How do I get a list of items with the distances in them?  Could I create a new class (e.g. ItemSearchResult), which would basically be the Item class plus a Distance property and return a list of those?  If so, how do I get NHiberante to map to that object?  Could I just replace <Item> with <ItemSearchResult> in your code and it would figure it out?

Comment: Or will I need to use something like AliasToBean?

Comment: You can't - sorry, I thought you only wanted the items ordered. Without mapping another property on your Item class, or adding a new result entity like in Abel's answer, NHibernate has nowhere to put the extra value.

Answer (score 0):

Ayende explains how to do this in the mapping files, without haveing to resort to passing SQL to your session:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx

Also see the Hibernate documentation regarding this issue (also relevant to NHibernate):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querysql.html